# Log slow loading pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, diagnostics

Do you guys know of a library/httpmodule for logging slow loading pages (perhaps for a specific treshold) in an ASP.NET environment?

Google did not yield any results.

It would not be too hard to implement on my own, but why re-invent the weel.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was in big need for this, I ended up writing my own using a `HttpModule` and a simple `Stopwatch`. This is a quick and dirty work but it's OK for me for now. It logs date and time, loading time in seconds, requested url and POST variables if any.

If anyone is interested, the source is [here](http://pastebin.com/hDektu3N). You just add it to your `httpModules` section in your web.config like so:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="SlowPageLogger" type="Namespace.BaseModule, Namespace" />  
</httpModules>
```

However, if someone comes up with a library, i'm more than happy to accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

This MSDN article may help: [ASP.NET Performance Monitoring, and When to Alert Administrators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx#monitor_perf_topic1)

This MSDN link is a little more current: [Performance Counters for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx)

You could hook into the **Request Execution Time** performance counter and log as you need.

Google Chrome has a great Timeline tool built into the developer browser tools. It won't log anything or show you what is wrong but it will give you an easy look at where to start looking if you are troubleshooting a single page.

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to ASP.NET environment but maybe you can try Yahoo YSLOW for Firebug.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Comment: That won't log slow loading pages.  Just let you analyse things from a clients perspective.

Comment: This is unfortunately not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a library that logs slow requests for my whole application.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at New Relic RPM, I know the Rails version allows slow pages logging, I haven't tested the ASP.NET version yet, but it sould do it :

http://newrelic.com/